# Unfollow Button will not DELETE

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, server

This project is a mock social media web application. Basically, I've been working on this Unfollow button and got the routes and everything set up, but there's something not connecting with the server.

Once I click on "Unfollow" the error on the console is:

`DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/users/follower/5ebef16ad7c54750f8690220 422 (Unprocessable Entity)`

```
  Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 422
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:59)
```

I believe it's something with the function in the controller for removing the follower, because the function to stop the user from following returns with a 200 server status. The function to remove a follower is

```
removeFollower: async function(req, res){
        const { user } = req.session.passport
        const userName = { user }.user
        try {
            console.log('removing follower')
            Account.findOne({ username: userName }, function (err, obj) { return obj._id }).then(
                userID =>
                    Account.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id },
                        { $pull: { followed: userID } }, { new: true })
            ).catch(err=>res.status(422).json(err))
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err) })
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, still a new dev.

Comment: This error is because your promise is unhandled. There should be an "await" statement somewhere in your code. Please give this docs a read: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: Not sure whether it's related, but you shouldn't mix callback with `Promises`. If you pass `function (err, obj) {}` you should not have to do `.then(userID => ...).catch(err => ...)` and vice versa